# How do i get headers Authorization?

Tags: reactjs, http, axios

We are utilizing axios in react to make a login post request like below. Then I'm trying to get the jwt token value stored in authorization in the response header, but when I console it, I get undefined.
If I check the response header in the network tab, the value is being passed, so what can I do?

```
const handleLogin: React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post('http://localhost:8080/login', {
        userName: EMAIL,
        password: PASSWORD,
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.headers);
        console.log(axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization);
        console.log(res.headers.Authorization);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });

  };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3orB.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmR3f.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getAuthorization()` method to get the token

```
res.headers.getAuthorization()
```

Even you did not get the  header try to console the whole header object `console.log(res)` or `res.headers.authorization` in lower case